# Заполнение qtablewidget runtime

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть проект, в нем обрабатывает внешняя библиотека, у которой есть функции обратного вызова. Когда происходит событие функция обратного вызова возвращает данные, эти данные передаются в другую функцию, а от туда через emit отправляются в слот для добавления этих данных в qtablewidget. Данные передаются по цепи, но в таблицу не заносятся. в чем может быть проблема?

P.S.: если что нибудь добавить в таблицу по нажатию кнопки, то все ок - 
передача сигнала

```
void sig_slot::some_func(int x, int y, char *z) //статическая функция для обратного вызова
{
    qDebug()<<"some_func"<<x<<y<<z; //показывает что получены данные
sig_slot *pmw=new sig_slot; 
pmw->get_table(z,y,z);//передаем
}
void sig_slot::get_table(int x, int y, char *z)
{
emit send_test(x, y, z); //слот
}
```

Заполнение таблицы:

```
void sig_slot::send_test( int x, int y, char *z)
{

QDateTime dt = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
int row = tableWidget->rowCount();
      tableWidget->insertRow(row);
      tableWidget->setColumnCount(4);

      QTableWidgetItem* item_dt = new QTableWidgetItem { dt.toString("dd.MM.yy hh.mm.ss") };
      item_dt->setBackground(Qt::red);
      tableWidget->setItem(row, 0, item_dt);


      QTableWidgetItem* item_ch = new QTableWidgetItem { QString::number(x)};
      item_ch->setBackground(Qt::green);
     tableWidget->setItem(row, 1, item_ch);

      QTableWidgetItem* item_wt = new QTableWidgetItem { QString::number(y)};
      item_wt->setBackground(Qt::red);
      tableWidget->setItem(row, 2, item_wt);

      QTableWidgetItem*item_pn = new QTableWidgetItem {QString::fromLocal8Bit(z)};
      item_pn->setBackground(Qt::green);
      tableWidget->setItem(row, 3, item_pn);
      qDebug()<<"func"<<x<<y<<z; //показывает что данные были переданы
}
```

А так все работает:

```
connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &sig_slot::t_table);

void sig_slot::t_table()
{
QDateTime dt = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
int row = tableWidget->rowCount();
      tableWidget->insertRow(row);
      tableWidget->setColumnCount(4);

      QTableWidgetItem* item_dt = new QTableWidgetItem { dt.toString("dd.MM.yy hh.mm.ss") };
      item_dt->setBackground(Qt::red);
      tableWidget->setItem(row, 0, item_dt);s.

      QTableWidgetItem* item_ch = new QTableWidgetItem { "test2"};
      item_ch->setBackground(Qt::green);
     tableWidget->setItem(row, 1, item_ch);

      QTableWidgetItem* item_wt = new QTableWidgetItem { "test2"};
      item_wt->setBackground(Qt::red);
      tableWidget->setItem(row, 2, item_wt);

      QTableWidgetItem*item_pn = new QTableWidgetItem {"test2"};
      item_pn->setBackground(Qt::green);
      tableWidget->setItem(row, 3, item_pn);
}
```

Comment: `через emit отправляются в слот для добавления` а слот-то тот вызывается?

Comment: да, и успешно передает данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем чтобы все заработало нужно делать глобальную переменную **sig_slot* globalObject;** в main.cpp и инициализируешь её там же.
Далее, в файле реализации в самом начале ставить строчку **extern sig_slot* globalObject;**

Answer (score 0):

Send_test можно вызвать напрямую из get_table. Если же вы хотите использовать механизм сигналов, то эмитировать надо **сигнал**, а **слот** должен быть к нему подключён с помощью connect. Правда, непонятно зачем это надо внутри одного объекта

Answer (score 0):

```
sig_slot *pmw=new sig_slot; 
pmw->get_table(z,y,z);//передаем
```

В этом месте вы создали новый объект sig_slot и для него вызываете функцию get_table, только к этому объекту не подключен никакой обработчик через connect.

Вам в этой функции не нужно создавать новый объект, а нужно получить доступ к уже созданному и для него вызывать get_table, как это сделать: через глобальную, статическую переменную, это уже другой вопрос.

```
void sig_slot::some_func(int x, int y, char *z) //статическая функция для 
обратного вызова
{
    qDebug()<<"some_func"<<x<<y<<z; //показывает что получены данные
    sig_slot *pmw=new sig_slot; 
    pmw->get_table(z,y,z);//передаем
}
```